# Assign a value to a group of rows pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a large DataFrame and I am interested in three main columns: individual id, education, and year. I would like to create a new variable called education1985 where I assign to all the individuals the education they had in 1985, no matter what year is in the row. I want to do that without a loop since my data is very large. Also, I want to do it without knowing the different individual's IDs in advance. Here I attach an example with a created data of what I need.

```
# This is the initial data frame : 
individual_id = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9]
education = [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,5,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,3]
year = [1984,1985,1986,1987,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1985,1986,1987,1989,1984,1985,1984,1985,1986,1985,1986,1985,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1987]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["id"] = individual_id
df["education"] = education
df["year"] = year

# And the desired outcome is create the variable educ85 : 

df2 = df.copy()
df2["educ85"] = educ85
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df = df.join(
    other=df[df.year==1985][['id','education']].set_index('id').rename(
        columns={'education': 'educ85'}
    ), 
    how='left', 
    on='id'
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the following error : ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['educ'], dtype='object').   However, I added , lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right'  and it worked! Honestly no idea how! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good job ;) read about joining tables. There are many examples in SQL but you can also find something in python too. Please accept the answer if it is working for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to like approaches that are relatively simple.

Initial data setup.

```
individual_id = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9]
education = [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,5,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,3]
year = [1984,1985,1986,1987,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1985,1986,1987,1989,1984,1985,1984,1985,1986,1985,1986,1985,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1987]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["id"] = individual_id
df["education"] = education
df["year"] = year
```

Filter the data down to the 1985 data and then create a dictionary mapping ID to Education.

```
d1985 = df[df.year == 1985]
d1985 = dict(zip(d1985.id, d1985.education))
```

Then, create your new DataFrame -

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['educ85'] = df2.id.replace(d1985)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description! Yes it does work! Still. it seems the other answer I recieved performs faster. Thanks a lot though!